# How to add data to mongoDB in python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am a python noob (working with it for less than a few hours).  I'm trying to read in twitter data and store it in a mongo database, but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twit_test.py", line 8, in on_receive
    db.posts.insert(data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pymongo-2.0.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/pymongo/collection.py", line 274, in insert
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pymongo-2.0.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/pymongo/database.py", line 249, in _fix_incoming
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pymongo-2.0.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/pymongo/son_manipulator.py", line 73, in transform_incoming
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twit_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    conn.perform()
```

My code is very simple:

```
import pycurl, json
import pymongo

STREAM_URL = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json"
USER = "XXXXXXXX"
PASS = "XXXXXXXX"
def on_tweet(data):
  tweet = json.loads(data)
  db.posts.insert(tweet)

from pymongo import Connection
connection = Connection()
db = connection.test
conn = pycurl.Curl()
conn.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "%s:%s" % (USER, PASS))
conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, STREAM_URL)
conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, on_tweet)
conn.perform()
```

I'm sure this is a VERY simple fix, hope you guys can help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On receive you have to buffer the content. When a "\r\n" comes, then you get a tweet and it can be stored in mongodb

```
def on_tweet(data):
    tweet = json.loads(data)
    db.posts.insert(tweet)


 buffer = ""

 def on_receive(data):
     buffer += data.strip()         
     if (data.endswith("\r\n")):    
         if buffer: 
             on_tweet(buffer)
         buffer = ""
```

EDIT : I though you were using old streaming api. "on_tweet" function should be enough

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following.  Do I only use the on_tweet function in lieu of the on_receive function?  I tried that and all of your code above, but neither worked.....

Answer (score 2):

PyMongo's `insert` method takes a dictionary, not a string. The error you're seeing is where PyMongo attempts to assign an `ObjectId` for the new record (since it doesn't yet have one) before sending to the database.

I think the error is in your `on_receive` function. Unless pycurl is converting the JSON for you automatically, it's very likely just giving you a raw string result from twitter's API. You should use the json module to decode the string, then handle the resulting type appropriately -- that is, if it's an array, iterate each item, determine whether it needs to be saved (i.e. whether you already have it in your database), and if not, then issue `insert` just on those elements which are new.

**EDIT:** You should also add the `safe=True` keyword argument to `insert`. If there is an error that is caught on the server side, you will then get an exception from PyMongo which will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: I don't understand your post.  I'm not using the save function, I'm using the insert item.  When i simply do a 'curl' on the command line to get tweets and copy/paste that using the same syntax, it works.

Comment: My mistake (a typo) -- but insert also requires a dictionary (i.e. a document) to save, not a string. You'll still need to process and convert the data received from `pycurl` into the correct format (i.e. a dictionary of the appropriate "shape") before you can save to MongoDB. Not sure what you mean about copy and paste...

Comment: I added a json.loads function to the callback function.  It doesn't error out but it fails to load into the DB as well.  Am I missing something else?

Comment: Updated the code.  Also to elaborate on copy/paste - if I do a curl on the command line and copy a tweet and paste it into the interactive MongoDB CLI using a db.posts.insert the tweet loads fine.

Answer (score 0):

The above edits/current code works.  I was incorrectly querying the DB and expecting to see more traffic through the mongo console than I did.

Thanks much to the guys who helped, you got me on teh right track and to the right answer!